# Scroll two layouts at different speed simultaneously

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have a frame layout which Contains Two layouts with scrollviews. The scrollViews are independent of one another.

What I want to achieve is when I scroll through top layout, the layout in the background should also scroll but at different speed. For example if I am scrolling up the background layout should scroll at half the speed of the scrolling on the top layout.

Do anyone know how can I implement this functionality?If you have any other good way to implement this, please suggest. Thanks.